# WordPress Dropdown Menu issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For some reason my WordPress generated menu is causing some issues when I try to display the drop-down. The parent menu item becomes full width and then covers the other items. This is what it looks like on hover state:

[image: Portfolio menu on hover state]

Here is a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/j55scjeq/

Here is the CSS:

```
        /* Navigation */

        #nav {
            margin: 100px 0;
            background-color: #E64A19;
            z-index: 999;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        /* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
         * and adding "position:reltive" */
        #nav ul {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            z-index:;
            }

        /* Positioning the navigation items inline */
        #nav ul li {
            margin: 0px -7px 0 0;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: #E64A19;
            max-width: 200px;
            }

        /* Styling the links */
        #nav a {
            display:block;
            padding:0 10px;
            color:#FFF;
            font-size:20px;
            line-height: 60px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        /* Background color change on Hover */
        #nav a:hover {
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        #nav ul li ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            z-index: 99;
        }

        /* Display Dropdowns on Hover  */
        #nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 99;
        }


        /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown  */
        #nav ul ul li {
            max-width:450px;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 99;
        }
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="nav"><div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-5164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-5164"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2787" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2756 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-2787"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4602" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4602"><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-5628" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5628"><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1023"><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-363" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-363"><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1022"><a href="#">Link five</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-362" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-362"><a href="#">Link six</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-356" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-356"><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-5709" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5709"><a href="#">Another Link 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-358"><a href="#">Another Link 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4883"><a href="#">Another Link 3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-835" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-835"><a href="#">Another Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-364" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-364"><a href="#">Our clients</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4709" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4709"><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-357"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-360" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-360"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul></div></nav>
```

Could someone please help me find a solution. I would just like the child UL to display in a nice column, overlapping the content underneath.

I can't figure this out. I'm not sure if its a problem with the HTML or the CSS. :/

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the `position: relative` to `position : absolute` -

```
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover  */
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute; /*Or you can simply remove it as you have already declared its position: absolute at #nav ul li ul */
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Try this and let me know if any issue.

**JSFiddel**   -  https://jsfiddle.net/j55scjeq/2/

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the #nav ul li positioning relative to keep the dropdown menu 
around the link area

and #nav ul li:hover > ul [changing the position from absolute to relative is the main proplem ]

```
Edite : https://jsfiddle.net/j55scjeq/3/
```

Comment: Thank you. The other guy beat you to the accepted answer but +1 for the reply :)